# How to Copy Current URL of Web Page in Fluid App with AppleScript/Service and Bind on Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: applescript, services, fluid.app

I'm using FluidApp Version 1.8.6 (2331) on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3. Sometimes I need to copy current URL of Web page in FluidApp. I want to do it with keyboard shortcut and I know I need to use a service for it.

So how do I create a service for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having issues using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> and you want an **AppleScript** *script* that runs as an **Automator** *Service*, in order to copy the **URL** of a **Fluid App**, created with **[Fluid](http://fluidapp.com)**, then here is an example scenario you could implement.

Under **macOS 10.12.3** using **Fluid** *(Version 1.8.6 (206))* and the **URL** *of this question*, I created a **Fluid App** named **Ask Different Question**.

[image: Ask Different Question Fluid App]

I them made an **Automator** *Service workflow* using a **Run AppleScript** *action* and the **AppleScript** *code* below.

```
set appName to "Ask Different Question"

tell application appName
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        set toolbarState to (name of every menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item 5 of menu bar 1 of application process appName)
        if toolbarState contains "Show Toolbar" then
            keystroke "t" using {option down, command down}
            set the clipboard to (get value of text field 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process appName)
            keystroke "t" using {option down, command down}
        else
            set the clipboard to (get value of text field 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process appName)
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

- Note that all you should have to change in the *code* above is the first line, `set appName to ...` where `...` is the name of your **Fluid App**. The rest of the *code* should then work *as is*.

In **Automator**, create a new *Service workflow*, adding a **Run AppleScript** *action* to it. Then replace the *default code* with the *code* above. Also change the *value* for **Service receives** to **no input** while selecting the target **Fluid App** for **in**, as shown in the image below. Then save the **Automator** *Service workflow*.

[image: Automator Image]

The next step is to assign a *keyboard shortcut* for the **Automator** *Service workflow* you've just created.

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, find your *service* and set its *shortcut*.

I used <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> as that was easy to remember using **U** for **URL**.

[image: Services Keyboard Shortcut Image]

The last thing you'll need to do, is add the **Fluid App** you created that will use the **Automator** *Service workflow* you've just created to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** as shown in the image below for the **Ask Different Question** app I created in **Fluid**.

[image: Security & Privacy Image]

Now when you're in the **Fluid App** you created and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, the **URL** will be copied to the **Clipboard** and from there you can *paste* it wherever you'd like.

Comment: Hi, again. It's working in the Automator. But it doesn't work with app itself and I met with an error alert (its says: "The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error.". 

By the way I created a screencast for this issue. You can watch it from here: https://cl.ly/jSe8

How can solve this issue?

Comment: @fatihturan, I made a Fluid App for Trillo and it works as my answer is written.  My first test I had a typo but then corrected it and it works in Script Editor, Automator and from the Trillo Fluid App. Test running the code in Script Editor and see that it works there too. I'll look at it again this evening, but I have things to do this afternoon.

Comment: Could it be a relationship if I do the same for another Fluid app? I've tried to apply other two Fluid app too... What do you think about this?

Comment: @fatihturan, There is definitely a conflict if you have more then one Fluid App as the primary executable inside each Fluid App application bundle is `/Contents/MacOS/FluidApp`. You might need to talk to the Developer about this.

Comment: @fatihturan, I could reproduce the error when having two Fluid App apps, one having a keyboard shortcut and the other just the service and no shortcut much less if they both had shortcuts. I'd have to uncheck/check the non-working one in Accessibility to get it to work again, which disabled the previous working one. So it seams only one can have the service much less a shortcut. This reminds me of my programming days in Windows when I'd subclass a process under another process and it looks like something like that is going on here, although it been far to many years for me to delve into that.

Comment: @fatihturan, Sadly, as written, it looks like my answer is only good for one Fluid App. :(

Answer (score 0):

Developer of Fluid here. I don't know much about Services, but in Fluid you can copy the current URL using keyboard shortcuts, but it requires *two*:

<kbd>⌘L</kbd> - to temporarily show and select the text of the URL location text field at the top.

<kbd>⌘C</kbd> - to copy the selected text.

<kbd>Esc</kbd> - to dismiss the toolbar at the top.

Comment: Its quite good tip but when I press CMD+L +, CMD+C and then ESC key, the address bar remains open. So, then I have to close it.

For this reason I want to copy the address with a single key.

Comment: Hi Todd, can you checkout [above reply](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275160/1556) and [comment](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275092/how-to-copy-current-url-of-web-page-in-fluid-app-with-applescript-service-and-bi/275160?noredirect=1#comment346694_275160)?